# Is it possible to send a message to a specific Skype Account using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, chatbot

Is it possible to send a message to a specific Skype Account using nodejs?

Example: I'm trying to send a message to a specific Skype account (Person 2) if my bot does not have the answer. Then, catch again the answer to resend to the first user (Person 1).

I'm using NodeJs v8.12, and BotBuilder v4
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have the bot's conversationId of the skype account, then you can send a proactive message. Conversation Id is found in `session.message.address.conversation.id` in nodeJs app.

When someone interacts with the bot say for the first time, you can save the `session.message.address` object (in string form) in your database.

```
const addressString = JSON.stringify(session.message.address)
// now save addressString to the database
```

Later you can retrieve this object (and convert it back to json) to send proavtive message.

```
const address = JSON.parse(addressString);

private sendProactiveMessage(message, address) {
  const msg = new BotBuilder.Message().address(address);
  msg.text(message);
  this.bot.send(msg);
}
```